# How to re-use same database with different migration scripts for different rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

How to re-use same database with different migration scripts for different rails apps. The following is the proposed structure, is this something which would work and is this a proper way to share the database?

```
rails-app1/db/migrate/s1.sql
rails-app1/db/migrate/s4.sql

rails-app2/db/migrate/s2.sql
rails-app2/db/migrate/s3.sql
rails-app2/db/migrate/s5.sql
```

I am using MySQL database

Comment: What database aer you using?  Looks like you're asking about multi-tenancy.

Comment: yes..you can.All you need to do is to create a db with similar roles..and then run the scripts...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider to create an API which will be the only one with rights to read/write in your database. Then, App1 and App2 will be consumers of this API.

What you are trying to do will create different database schemes with different (or duplicated) model definitions for the same Database... It sounds dangerous.